# Jda discord bot hosting on heroku problems

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea, discord, discord-jda

I wanted to make a discord bot because it looked cool, after some research I decided to use java (Jda) with IntelliJ as my IDE. I have never use java before so I am quite the noob. I made a simple bot and wanted to host it on Heroku but there my issues started. I got a

> No default language could be detected for this app.

error message and searched stack overflow and found a similar question with a link to a Heroku documentation site.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea

I followed the steps but when I run the git download of maven with the settings it provided it gives me the following error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project helloworld: Compilation failure
```

I have no idea what this means so my question is, can I run a discord java bot on Heroku, am I on the right track and if so how do I fix this error. Or is there a simpler way for a noob like me to host a discord bot (preferably for free)?

Here are some details:

I have linked my Heroku account with Github.
This is my repository https://github.com/SebastiaanTheCoder/cozy-games.I have the latest version of IntelliJ and java. If you need any more details, feel free to ask and I will provide them as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.